# Maximum Area Rectangle In Histogram. Find dimensions of the Max Rectangle

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I am trying to find maximum area histogram but I would like to track the height and width of the maximum rectangle. I tried different ways by initializing and tracking global width but not able to do it.

This is the code for max area histogram that I have written.
Used this video to code. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVIh0snn4Qc&t=888s

```
class Solution:
def largestRectangleArea(self, hist):
    stack=[]; i=0; area=0
    while i<len(hist):
        if stack==[] or hist[i]>hist[stack[len(stack)-1]]:
            stack.append(i)
        else:
            curr=stack.pop()
            width=i if stack==[] else i-stack[len(stack)-1]-1
            area=max(area,width*hist[curr])
            i-=1
        i+=1
    while stack!=[]:
        curr=stack.pop()
        width=i if stack==[] else len(hist)-stack[len(stack)-1]-1

        area=max(area,width*hist[curr])
    return area, 

def maximalRectangle(self, matrix):
    if matrix==[]: return 0
    a=[0 for i in range(len(matrix[0]))]; maxArea=0
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
            a[j]=a[j]+1 if matrix[i][j]=='1' else 0

        maxArea=max(maxArea, self.largestRectangleArea(a)[0])
        print (self.largestRectangleArea(a))
    return maxArea


if __name__ == "__main__":
print( Solution().maximalRectangle([['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1'],
                                    ['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1'],
                                    ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1'],
                                    ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1']]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace in-built `max` operation with own implementation - when you get better result, remember values of `width` and `hist[curr])` as the best ones (at that moment). Like this:

```
  #area=max(area,width*hist[curr])
  newarea = width*hist[curr] 
  if (newarea>area):
        area = newarea
        bestw = width
        besth = hist[curr]
```

Comment: Thanks. I was doing a stupid mistake. I was printing the width in the while loop.